# Groovy - Parse SOAP response XML to get data

Tags: soap, groovy, xml-parsing

I have the below value as text. I need to parse the XML and get the value for each of them. Please suggest how to do in Groovy

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:WS_CTM_People_ICEVA">
         <ns0:getListValues>
            <ns0:Person_ID>PPL000000301739</ns0:Person_ID>
            <ns0:Submitter>soehler</ns0:Submitter>
            <ns0:Profile_Status>Enabled</ns0:Profile_Status>
            <ns0:Locale2>en_US</ns0:Locale2>
            <ns0:VIP>No</ns0:VIP>
            <ns0:Client_Sensitivity>Standard</ns0:Client_Sensitivity>
         </ns0:getListValues>
      </ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your xml is in a String in the variable `xml`, then you can do:

```
def mapOfValues = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
                                  .Body
                                  .GetListBy_QualificationResponse
                                  .getListValues.children().collectEntries {
    [it.name(), it.text()]
}
```

Which makes `mapOfValues` equal to a Map containing:

```
[
    'Person_ID':'PPL000000301739',
    'Submitter':'soehler',
    'Profile_Status':'Enabled',
    'Locale2':'en_US',
    'VIP':'No',
    'Client_Sensitivity':'Standard'
]
```

Comment: @Nilotpol does this help? Did you able to test using this? I have been using this same logic but I am only getting the values not as name value pair.